# Relationship between closest points on two lines with a line and intersection point of the plane (formed by the two lines) with a line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Say I have two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$, that are perpendicular to each other, and together form a plane $P$. I also have a line $L_3$.

For lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ we can find the closest point to line $L_3$, which we can call $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively.

We can also find the intersection point between the plane $P$ and $L_3$, which we can call $p_3$.

My question is would the projection of $p_3$ onto lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ respectively, be equal to points $p_1$ and $p_2$ and if so how can I prove this?